# Nginx 403: directory index of "/home/deploy/MyApp/current/public/" is forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I have set up a rails project with nginx and passenger. I'm getting a 403 when trying to access the site. This is my config file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com`:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name www.mysite.com *.mysite.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deploy/mysite/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        #try_files $uri;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

My `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` are correctly set in `nginx.conf` and I have set write/read permissions on the app's root/, root/current and root/current/public folders for the nginx user.

Any ideas? Thx in advance.

Comment: Your error says that nginx is trying to get a directory listing, which means it's not trying to render anything rails provides. Have you restarted nginx after turning on passenger ?

Comment: also add mysite.com to server_name (you have *.mysite.com, which i'm not sure works with empty subdomain.

Comment: @xyious I have added mysite.com to the server_name. Regarding passenger, that could be it but should I start it on port 80? I get a permission denied for that.

Comment: When do you get a permission denied ? in the config you posted you already started on port 80. Is there another server running on port 80 ?

Comment: @xyious No I mean Nginx is listening on port 80. Maybe that is irrelevant, sorry. But When I do for example `passenger-config restart-app` it says `Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.`. So do I have to start it manually, as a deamon or something?

Comment: If it's installed and configured correctly passenger should start with nginx. Have you restarted nginx since you changed the configuration ?

Comment: @xyious Yes I have restarted nginx several times. That's what I thought too, that it should start automatically with this configuration.

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs of nginx ?

Comment: @xyious Yes I'm getting this: `directory index of "/home/deploy/mysite/current/public/" is forbidden, client: <my ip>, server: www.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.com"`

Comment: Did you uncomment # passenger_root /some-filename/locations.ini; and 
# passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby; ? What's the output of sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install

Comment: @xyious Yes, they are uncommented. The output is `Everything looks good. :-)` So yeah.. I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: try putting 2 lines into your root / directive: root /home/deploy/mysite/current/public; passenger_enabled on;

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify these two options as well

```
passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby;
```

You can check the path of your passenger installation with

```
passenger-config --root
```

And Ruby version with

```
which ruby
```

compare these outputs with what you specify.

Comment: I have already set up all these things as you describe. I'm getting a 403 Permission denied by nginx so it seems to me that it is nginx having the problem.